# Execute run time query VS storing results in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance

I am working on very large database. Due to the privacy policy I can't write the original schema but I can give an example similar to that.

Example
Let's say I have a product table. It is the main table. It had many details and for those individual details I created other tables like product_detail_1 product_detail_2 product_detail_3 upto 10. These details tables contains many different values.

Now all these tables have a foreign key which refers to the primary key in a product table. So if I want any particular data then it's very easy to retrieve once I have the key. .

Now my question is if I want to display results based on particular details then which method I should follow?

Method 1:
I run query everytime I want to search. 
In this case the query will be too long because the query likely to contain 4 to 7 where clauses on different detail tables so it will take some time to execute.

OR

Method 2:
I store the result of every search query in a new table. 
Benefits of this technique is 
 - If the same query executed again then  the result is already available so it won't take much time. 
So if I store query result in a table with text datatype column is there any limitations for length in column?

Or should I try method 1? 
I'm using mysql database

Comment: Your second method is caching. This is already handled on many levels: disk caches, RAM, database caches... unless you have some solid statistics that indicate you have a caching issue then I suggest you don't try and rewrite another manual cache. Do you have an actual performance issue. You're better off addressing any specific real performance issue that you may have.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes performance is the problem. Queries require 1 to 7 seconds to execute based upon thier complexity. So if I use method 2 then i is there any constrains on text datatype column ?

Comment: I suggest you first look into indexing, RAM,  and other database improvements before you develop your own caching system

Comment: Have you timed Method 1?  It is normally what people do.  Method 2 is duplicating what the Query cache can give you for free.